# Facebook API people search filtered by country

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to search people using the Facebook API (Graph API or FQL, whichever works).
Up to this point, it's working just fine but I can't get it to be filtered by country or language.

I'm currently retrieving this URL:

```
'https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=' . somename . '&type=user&access_token=' . $access_token
```

I have tried adding &locale=... but that didn't work either.

Comment: what is the locale value in your URL?

Comment: It's not in this one, but I had it in there before, which didnt work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is not possible with Facebooks API.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mccain%20chips&type=post&locale=en_US
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to search for users, not for posts

Comment: so, use type=user, whats problem ?

Comment: It has no effect, the results with locale=en_US and locale=de_DE are the same... (or any combination of locales I tried for that matter)

Comment: I hope, that you use access token ?

Comment: Well for me it does work I can see different results for different localities

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to filter according to a locale but there is a way to have the locale field with users informations :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=NAME&type=user&fields=locale,name&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Comment: Yeah thats the whole problem I'm having, I know I can request the field but I cant filter based on the field...

Comment: I've searched one more time ... and didn't find anything more. Can't you really filter those results on your side after the request ?

Comment: Yes, but considering there are quite a lot of different locales that would be really inefficient, so I'm looking for a better solution

Answer (score 0):

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=SOME_SEARCH&type=user&center=37.76,122.427&distance=1000


http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=SOME_SEARCH&type=user&locale=en_US
```

Comment: As I've said, changing the locale or center has no effect, when searching for users Facebook seems to ignore these parameters

Answer (score 0):

one of the more sophisticated methods is by fetching data from

```
www.facebook.com/search/results.php?q=paritosh&type=users&lo=812057
```

You can also fetch data from this link but it requires you logged in

```
http://www.facebook.com/search/ajax/?__a=1&lo=812057&q=paritosh&type=users&__user=1818667565
```

describing parameters :

- lo=location point
- q= query
- type= users
- __user = yours profile user id .