# Limit Facebook Graph Queries

Tags: facebook

Is there any possible way to limit facebook graph query results to a specific country and not only by language ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Do you want to get post people have made from a specific country? Can you give an example of the type of query you are trying to run please?

Comment: A good example might be a query which search for every public post made in australia which contain the word " phone"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is currently possible. This was previously answered at the link below:

[facebook public posts filtered by country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916495/facebook-public-posts-filtered-by-country)